# Mysql join the two tables so that the data from those table should come from a single table

Tags: mysql

I have two table like this listings and listing documents
The listing table is like this

```
listing_id  type test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9 
9            
124
6
45
```

Here I have showed only some columns but I have a huge database
and other table is listing_documents. So the table is like this

```
document_id  listing_id  folder     filename
000564          000006    folder1    file12
000549          000045    folder4    file56
000760          000124    folder6    file67
000456          000009    folder8    file99
```

Now I want to join those two table as you can see the two table has the listing_id. So I made my query like this

```
SELECT l.listing_id as l_listing_id, ld.*
FROM listings as l
JOIN listing_documents AS ld ON ld.listing_id = LPAD(l.listing_id, 6, '0')
ORDER BY l_listing_id
```

But its only showing the listing_id from listing table. I want to join both the tables so both tables data should come in a single table. So can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

use Right Join to join the tables

Comment: Note that RIGHT JOIN is a vanishingly rare commodity on SO. [mysql] LEFT [OUTER] JOIN = 9000 hits. RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN = 800 hits. Just sayin'